# how to get src of current "active" image inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery

I want to pull the src of the active image inside bootstrap carousel each time it changes. Below is what I have now which works for the first image, but doesn't change when the next one fires.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#galleryCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {  
       var src = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
       alert(src);
     });  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, this is my approach.

Since the slide is an animation event, apparently the class toggle fire at a different time than the event itself.

```
$('#galleryCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () { 
  setTimeout(function(){
    var src = $('.active').find('img').attr('src'); alert(src);
  }, 300);
 });
```

I have put 300, but you have to put the same time you used for the carousel animation (180 by default, it may depend on the version) it would be safer to put a bigger number.

Answer (score 0):

you must use `slid.bs.carousel`event :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#galleryCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {  
       var src = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
       alert(src);
     });  
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

"slide.bs.carouse" occurs when the carousel is about to slide from one item to another and "slid.bs.carousel" occurs when the carousel has finished sliding from one item to another

Answer (score 0):

You can try use my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $('#galleryCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {  
       var img = e.relatedTarget.querySelector('img');
       var src = e.relatedTarget.querySelector('img').src
       console.log("img:", img);
       console.log("src:", src);
     });  
});
```