# How to get the src value of an image tag with an active class name in carousel?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this sample Carousel:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Can you help me to get the src of the image tag that is active in the carousel display?

Comment: Are you using a plugin to make your Carousel ? You need to include a bit of your javascript code, as with only the HTML we can't get anything …

Comment: Just a simple carousel in bootstrap sir.

Comment: Hence, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49052546/how-to-get-src-of-current-active-image-inside-bootstrap-carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the desired element and get its `src` attribute..

```js
//let activeEle = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
let activeEle = document.querySelector('.carousel-item.active img');
console.log(activeEle.getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="thisisSource" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Ranjan. It really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target the element and [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the source:

```
document.querySelector('.carousel-item.active > img').getAttribute('src')
```

```js
var activeElImgSrc = document.querySelector('.carousel-item.active > img').getAttribute('src');
console.log(activeElImgSrc);
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../test" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun. It really helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the events available in bootstrap carousel plugin

```
$('#carouselId').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  console.log($(e.relatedTarget).find('img').prop('src'))
})
```